# Is there a way to delete a script file via script?

Tags: google-apps-script

It is simple:

1. a script of mine duplicates a Google Sheet, which contains several scripts;
2. the duplicated spreadsheet is personalised for uses different from the original ones;
3. In order to avoid unwanted actions, I need to remove a script file from the duplicated spreadsheet.

Which way? By managing properties? If yes, I did not understand how, but I suspect there is another way...
Thanks.

Comment: In some way, I solved. By putting a flag cell in a hidden cell of the original spreadsheet for yes/not onOpen activating add-on menu. When the script copies the spreadsheet, set also the flag to FALSE. So, the onOpen script skips the add-on menus on the basis of the FALSE value of the hidden cell, through an IF statement. It works.

Comment: If you just want to delete one or two functions you can use apps script API projects.upDateContent

Answer (score 1):

Great thing you found a workaround, I wanted to share some others in case you find them handy:

Assuming that the script has multiple .gs files I don't believe there is a way to delete them however we can turn them off through the code by doing something like this:

```js
if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId() === "your main spreadsheet file ID here"){

//---All the code---//

}
```

The way that this work is comparing the ID of the current sheet using SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId() with the value between the quotation marks, This is a hard coded value that will have to match your source spreadsheet ID, since the copy will have a different ID then the code will not run.

This can be used even if the sheet has a single .gs file other alternatives are:

- [Deleting the triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#:%7E:text=/**%0A%C2%A0*-,Deletes%20a%20trigger,-.%0A%C2%A0*%20%40param%20%7Bstring)
- [Copying only the sheets values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo) (Requires advanced spreadsheets service)

I hope you can find this information useful!